# Why does Cloudbees Jenkins intermittently fail with Access denied error for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, cloudbees

We have setup Cloudbees Jenkins to run integration test job whenever it detects a commit in Github. But for some strange reason, some intermittent builds fail with the following error:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In our Integration Test job, we do the following:

1. Drop MySQL database if it exists.
2. Create a new DB for Integration Tests.
3. Run Integration Tests (Junit)

We had set the password for  MySQL admin once to 'mysql' for the root user -- by executing a shell command in the job. Later we removed it because it failed the next time, giving us an indication that the password doesn't need to be set everytime by the job.

Any inputs on why this might be happening would help.

Comment: I was able to workaround this problem by adding the following in Jenkins on cloudbees: mysqladmin -u root password 'mysql' --socket=/home/jenkins/mysql/mysql.sock >> temp.txt  The redirection ensured that if the command fails, the build won't stop. And when password is blank, it would set the password.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudbees platform uses a slave pool, and your build may occur on a node it already has been built on (allocation algorithm tries to gives you such one, so that you get all dependencies already provisioned) but you sometime will have build to start on a fresh new node. So your build needs to be fully reproducible in both situations.

Possible workaround is to make this pasword initialization conditional to some way for you to detect the DB is already setup, or to enforce a full reset so you can safely run the init command on every build